# How do I access browser and browser_version in this JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON response (already parsed as JSON so not need `$.parseJSON` or so on):

```
{
  "raw": {
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36",
    "os": {
      "windows": true,
      "mac": false,
      "ios": false,
      "android": false,
      "linux": false,
      "unix": false,
      "firefox-os": false,
      "chrome-os": false,
      "windows-phone": false,
      "ps4": false,
      "vita": false,
      "unknown": false
    },
    "browser": {
      "chrome": true,
      "firefox": false,
      "safari": true,
      "opera": false,
      "ie": false,
      "ms-edge": false,
      "ps4": false,
      "vita": false,
      "unknown": false
    },
    "device": {
      "android": false,
      "ipad": false,
      "iphone": false,
      "ipod": false,
      "blackberry": false,
      "firefox-os": false,
      "chrome-book": false,
      "windows-phone": false,
      "ps4": false,
      "vita": false,
      "unknown": false
    },
    "os_version": {
      "windows-3-11": false,
      "windows-95": false,
      "windows-me": false,
      "windows-98": false,
      "windows-ce": false,
      "windows-2000": false,
      "windows-xp": false,
      "windows-server-2003": false,
      "windows-vista": false,
      "windows-7": false,
      "windows-8-1": true,
      "windows-8": false,
      "windows-10": false,
      "windows-phone-7-5": false,
      "windows-phone-10": false,
      "windows-nt-4-0": true,
      "unknown": false
    }
  },
  "os": "windows",
  "browser": "chrome",
  "device": "unknown",
  "os_version": "windows-8-1",
  "browser_version": "43.0.2357.81"
}
```

I need to access `browser` and `browser_version` and I am doing as follow:

```
jsonVar.raw.browser
jsonVar.raw.browser_version
```

But I got:

```
{"chrome":true,"firefox":false,"safari":true,"opera":false,"ie":false,"ms-edge":false,"ps4":false,"vita":false,"unknown":false}
```

How do I access those two keys on the JSON?

Comment: Doesn't look like its under `raw`, but in the base variable... so.. `jsonVar.browser_version`, etc.

Comment: In the future, either post it in a formatter, or use your IDE's auto formatting feature, then just follow the cursor as you scroll down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following.

```
jsonVar.browser
jsonVar.browser_version
```

Will return the desired values.